# Downloading a file replaces the content with html

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, csv, download

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC in Visual Studio, and when I click a button on the Index.html page, it is supposed to initiate a file download.

The file structure is:

```
~/Layer1/Layer2/(Index.html and Data.csv).
```

I have the href pointing to "Data.csv", the file I want to download. Instead of downloading the contents of the file, it reads it as another webpage and downloads the HTML page .../Index/Data.csv. So when it opens in excel there's a bunch of html content, not the csv content of the file.

Edit. Here's the a tag (using Knockout for the data-bind):

```
<a class="btn" data-bind="click: exportToCSV" download>EXPORT TO CSV</a>
```

The exportToCSV function modifies makes a call to a function, modifies the csv file, and then does:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = "Data.csv";
link.href = "Data.csv";
link.click();
```

That creates a new element with the reference to the file and "clicks" it.

Comment: It seems to be a broken link/reference. May u provide the html source (especially the a tag)?

Comment: It sounds like you need to set the content type of the response to a CSV file, not HTML

Comment: Do you perhaps have a browser extension installed that parses and formats CSV for display within the browser?

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this is to have your button post/get to an action that returns a FileResult which the browser will then do whatever its defaults say to do with a file download.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: That makes some sense. Would you mind going into some detail about how to post/get to the action? I'm new to MVC so I'm kind of confused about where return the File and the general execution order. Currently I have the javascript go to a function in a ApiController that modifies the CSV file. Do I return the file from there? Also should I do this all in the ApiController or just the Controller?